# Itertools cartesian product without order

Tags: python, python-itertools

EDIT:  user2357112 correctly marked my question as a duplicate. The linked answer works for my question.

I'll leave this question up, since I think it is worded differently than the linked question and might help others get to the right place.

---

I would like to take the permutation between all of the indices in a list.

For example, for the list ['a', 'b', 'c'], I want to iterate over indices `i` and `j` so that I can compare 'a' with 'a', 'b', 'c', etc.

That's basically just two nested for loops, so *product* from itertools does the trick nicely.

But it's doing basically twice the work that I need it to. I just need the upper triangular (i, j) pairs (so, unordered pairs-- *e.g.* if (0,1) is iterated over, then (1,0) isn't needed).

I thought that would definitely be an already-answered thing, but I can't find it. Could you help to answer or, if this is a duplicate, point me in the right direction? Thanks!

---

What I have:

```
from itertools import product

exList = ['a', 'b', 'c']

for i,j in product(range(len(exList)), range(len(exList))):
    print([i,j])

---
Out:

[0, 0]
[0, 1]
[0, 2]
[1, 0]
[1, 1]
[1, 2]
[2, 0]
[2, 1]
[2, 2]
```

But that's twice the computation that I need, `[0, 1]` and `[1, 0]` are redundant, for example.

So the output of itertools is an ordered pair. I would like an unordered pair--like a triangular  matrix.

What I would like:

```
from itertools import product

exList = ['a', 'b', 'c']

helpfulFunction(exList)

---
Out:

[0, 0]
[0, 1]
[0, 2]
[1, 1]
[1, 2]
[2, 2]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do an `if` statement and filter if `j` is greater or equals to `i`, only `print` then:

```
for i,j in product(range(len(exList)), range(len(exList))):
    if j >= i:
        print([i, j])
```

**MUCH BETTER:**

Use `combinations_with_replacement`:

```
for i, j in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(range(len(exList)), 2):
    print(i, j)
```

Both output:

```
[0, 0]
[0, 1]
[0, 2]
[1, 1]
[1, 2]
[2, 2]
```

Answer (score 3):

How about using [`itertools.combinations_with_replacement`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement)?

```py
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement
a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
list(combinations_with_replacement(a, 2))
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2)]
```

This would allow you to do:

```py
for i, j in combinations_with_replacement(range(len(a)), 2):
   print(i, j)

0 0
0 1
0 2
1 1
1 2
2 2
```